# How do I make the Dynamics 365 Web API default the ownerid like the SDK does?

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata

When I create an entity using the Organization Service in Dynamics 365, if I don't specify the entity's owner, the OwnerID is set to the identity of the user whose credentials are used to authenticate to the Organization Service.

However when I access the web API, by using a client generated using the [Microsoft.OData.Client](https://github.com/OData/odata.net) tool, calling SaveChangesAsync throws an exception, saying that the ownerid cannot be set to NULL.

I am authenticating using the client credentials grant with username and password (I know this is not a recommended practice, but the access token is accepted, so it's a proof of concept for now).

I don't know the ownerid. How do I make the web API default this value in the same way as the SDK?

Comment: Can you read data? Can you modify data? When you connect with the WebApi you should be authenticated as a user as well

Answer (score 0):

You could try explicitly [impersonating the user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/impersonate-another-user-web-api) - you will need to know their user id.

> There are two ways you can impersonate a user, both of which are made
>   possible by passing in a header with the corresponding user id.
>
> 1. Preferred: Impersonate a user based on their Azure Active Directory
>      (AAD) object id by passing that value along with the header
>      CallerObjectId.
> 2. Legacy: To impersonate a user based on their systemuserid you can
>      leverage MSCRMCallerID with the corresponding guid value.

```
POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/accounts HTTP/1.1  
CallerObjectId: e39c5d16-675b-48d1-8e67-667427e9c084  
Accept: application/json  
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8  
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0  
OData-Version: 4.0  

{"name":"Sample Account created using impersonation"}
```

You could also try setting the [ownerid explicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg326155(v%3Dcrm.8)#remarks) on the create call, again you will need to know their user id. Also check your users has the create and read permissions.

> By default the caller becomes the owner for the new record. However,
>   for the caller to own the new record, it must have both Create and
>   Read privileges for the entity. ... Alternatively, you can set the
>   ownerid property to the ID of another user.